# Connecting to online mongo database server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hey guys l am currently having some trouble connecting to my mongo database on the server. l currently have this with code to connect to my server:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://username:password@197.342.145.22:3085/Anime",(err,database) =>{
 if (err) return console.log(err)
  require('./app/routes')(app, database);
  app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log("listening to "+port); 
  });
})
```

but it is returning with this error everytime l try to connect when l run my node server:

```
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26) name: 'MongoError', message: 'read ECONNRESET' }
```

if someone could assist me by telling me of what l am doing wrong that would be nice.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Either the server is not running at that host and port or a firewall rejects your connection

Comment: Did you try connecting to mongo from shell or some ui (like ROBO 3T?   [link](https://robomongo.org/) ) does it work?

Did you try pinging your server's IP?

Did you try connecting to another mongo instance that you know is working well?

Comment: l have actually tried both ways and l keep on getting the same error. Thanks for the assistance though

Comment: Better than ping is [nmap](https://nmap.org) ; this will more reliably tell you if the mongo service on a remote server is accessible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that address you provide is not valid IP address. You can see it yourself on an [ip validator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/directipverify.html). Simply copy and paste `197.342.145.22` there. You will get:

[image]

The rest of your code is correct, and when you provide valid IP it is going to connect to MongoDB.